# PHP - AJAX Call or is there an alternative?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a school project using HTML5/Bootstrap 3 CSS and PHP and I have a question regarding PHP & Javascript(jQuery Ajax).

So i have a link "Click Me" that basically opens a remote php file (let's call it edit.php) in a modal box through the code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="prijzenWijzigen.php" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a>
```

[image: Image 1]

The value's (ID from database) and text from the listbox is generated through PHP and works fine. I wrote some testcode to test if it alert's me the selected item's value and that also works!

[image: Image 2]

What I want to do is:

Get the value from the selected item ( got the code for it ) and pass it through to edit.php 
so that I can manipulate it in edit.php. My issue is HOW do I pass the selected value to the edit.php page. I have googled and searched some code through AJAX calls to a PHP page but it's usually just something messy and code I really don't need.

Thanks in advance for the help !

**EDIT**

This is what i'm getting now when I use AJAX to pass down the selected item's value:

[image: Image3]

What I want to achieve now is get the reply ( which apparently is the entire edit.php page ) and put it inside the modal box as u see in picture 2 above. Is this still possible using AJAX ?

Comment: By making a form? Or pass the value with $_GET

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to send data from your html view to your php program. The best way in your case is through ajax. If you use jQuery, use `$.ajax()` method. Examples below should work fine

Comment: Yes. I want to pass the value from the selected item ( which is the ID in the MySQL database of the item ) to edit.php. In edit.php im gonna get info from the DB with the passed value ( through ajax I guess ). I've never in my life used ajax so ... :D

Comment: Heh, as you can see, it is really easy. After, you should take a look to `$.post()` and `$.get()` jquery methods. You are beginning to discover a fresh world and I'm sure that you will use this lots of times from here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be your ajax call code.

```
$.ajax({
  url : "edit.php?selected="+$("#selectMenuId :selected").val(),
  type : "GET",
  success : function(data) {
  // do something ehere if the call was successful

  },
  error : function(data) {
  // do something here if the call failed
  }
});
```

Inside your PHP:

```
$selectedValue = $_GET["selected"];
```

Comment: If I just want it to pass stuff to the edit.php page, is it necesaary to create a succes part ? I just want to use AJAX to pass the selected item and the php file does the rest .

Comment: I'm testing this with but the thing is I also want to GO to the edit.php page because its a html5 page on its own. And from there I can do whatever I want with the ?selected= . Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Forgot to mention space between the selector and :selected.I have updated the answer

Comment: Sweet! This piece of code works as I checked it in the console! Thanks ! Next question is: How do I open the page with the passed parameters? Is this also in the AJAX call or ...?

Comment: After making the ajax call, the server page edit.php will process the data and return you the response (JSON/HTML). Based on the response, you need to construct the next page

Comment: So it's not possible to just to pass the parameters, go to that page ( or in my case display that page in a modal box bootstrap 3 ) and play around with the passed parameter. Isn't this possible in Jquery

Comment: You can do, in that case you can use `$.load('edit.php?selected='+$("#selectMenuId :selected").val())` in the modal window. So the click event will trigger the modal window and make the ajax call. In the modal window, the data will be rendered

Comment: Editted the question to be more visible haha :D I'm not really familiar with Jquery so ... :P Do i have to put that piece of code inside the AJAX call ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54187/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-user3511568).

Comment: Thanks for everything.  Thaught me a lot about Ajax

Comment: It's my pleasure! Am glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

To do this with bootstrap remote modal you would remove the data attributes (data-toggle, data-target, ...) and use javascript to trigger the modal instead.

```
// Trigger the modal when the button with the id modalButton is pressed.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button#modalButton').click(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            remote: 'prijzenWijzigen.php?selected=' + $('#select').val()
        });
    });
});

// Remove the modal content when the modal is closed so it will reload
// the content if you change the selection and press the button again.
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

And in your HTML

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<button id="modalButton" class="btn btn-info">Click me !</button>
```

In your PHP you would then use, as suggested below

`$_GET["selected"];`

Here's a working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fUxcg/

Answer (score 0):

you can give the id to select box, and when you call ajax then you can take value of select box from id like :

```
var value = document.getElementById("sel_box").value;
```

where sel_box is id of select box;

and then you can use value variable and pass into the AJAX request in URL like:

```
edit.php?id=value;
```

and in edit.php you can get :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Thanks & Regard

Pulkit Jalani

Comment: Please use the format tools: [http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url : "edit.php",
  data: {
          data: $('#selectId').find(":selected").val(),
          data2: $('#select2Id').find(":selected").val()
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#target").html(data); /*return result from edit.php*/    
  },
});
```